# Сохранён где либо в памяти размер массива с++

Tags: c++, массивы

При использовании оператора `delete[]` с динамическими массивами мы не указываем нигде длину массива, который мы удаляем. Или при использовании `range-based-for-loop`, мы опять же не указываем ни где размер массива, по которому будем итерироваться. Складывается ощущение, что где-то сохранен размер массива, к которому имеют доступ оператор `delete[]` и `range-based-for-loop`, так ли это?

Comment: Это надо спрашивать у менеджера памяти :) *Стандартного* пути получить этот размер нет.

Comment: range-based-for-loop нельзя использовать с динамическим массивом.

Comment: range-based-for-loop можно использовать только с классами, для которых определён итератор и методы begin/end. По ним и определяется конец контейнера (не массива).

Comment: Ну, не только с классами, с обычными массивами (не динамическими) тоже можно. Т.к. количество элементов в массиве является частью его типа, то с определением количества итераций проблем не возникает.

Comment: Правильное ощущение (см., например, [man malloc_usable_size](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html))

Comment: malloc и Jemalloc вроде как умеет - https://linux.die.net/man/3/jemalloc

Comment: @wololo, я тоже так думаю, но почему-то не могу нигде найти, не могли бы вы привести текст в котором об этом говорится, если это возможно

Comment: См. описание the range-based цикла for  в [`stmt.ranged`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged). Касательно массивов, непосредственно пункт [`stmt.ranged/1.3.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1.3.1): «if the `for-range-initializer` is an expression of `array type R`, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `range` and `range + N`, respectively, where `N` is the **array bound**.». В этом же разделе стандарта есть [пример](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#example-1), в котором циклом перебирается обыкновенный массив.